# How do I set up Mysql Cluster?

Tags: server, mysql, ndb

I am trying to setup `mysql-cluster-gpl-7.1.17-linux-i686-glibc23.tar.gz` on `ubuntu 10.04` server for the past 3 weeks and not successful yet.

The links I followed are:

> http://stepbysteparticles.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=48&Itemid=54
>
> http://cyrenity.wordpress.com/2010/08/12/howto-setup-mysql-cluster-beginners-tutorial/
>
> http://tech.jocke.no/2011/03/13/mysql-cluster-how-to-with-load-balancing-failover/
>
> http://www.lod.com/whitepapers/mysql-cluster-howto.html
>
> http://blog.rimuhosting.com/2011/07/06/building-database-clusters-with-mysql/

All the configurations in the above links are almost same with some slight changes and I just gave a try of all if any works but none.

I already made a post in [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/334413/mysql-cluster-not-working-on-ubuntu) but I am still could not able to make it work.

I always come back here if nothing works out after many tries and now I am.

Also I am not understanding whether `mysql-server` or `mysql-client` need to be installed along with `mysql-cluster` else `mysql-cluster` alone is enough for running `mysqld` on SQL nodes. In my case the setup is `3 nodes=(data1+sql1 + data2+sql2 + mgmt node)`.

**Frequent errors**:

> /etc/init.d/mysql.server start

Output:

```
Starting MySQL
 * Couldn't find MySQL manager (/usr/bin/mysqlmanager) or server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)
```

I even tried copying `/usr/local/mysql/bin/*` to `/usr/bin` but still no use as it was telling `. * Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.` while trying to start!

> While trying to start mysql daemon on data/sql node
>
> cd /usr/local/mysql
>
> ./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf &

Output:

```
[1] 2338
root@web2:/usr/local/mysql# 111208 15:53:47 mysqld_safe Logging to syslog.
111208 15:53:47 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
111208 15:53:47 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/web2.pid ended

[1]+  Done                    ./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf
```

Anybody take up and help me here please?. Anybody clarify if there is any problem with ubuntu or with cluster config?. I have to implement this on cloud servers once I am successful.

Thank you!

**Update**:1

Now on SQL/Data nodes I have had already removed `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` which I generally install as a basic package of any fresh installation. I removed them by running following command and on both of the nodes only `mysql-cluster` is available which I could not able to setup:

> apt-get remove mysql-client mysql-client-5.1 mysql-client-core-5.1
>   mysql-common mysql-server mysql-server-5.1 mysql-server-core-5.1

**Update**:2

I have fixed the issues I had. Now I have the following things left to be done.

1. What is the best method to Add/Remove `mgmt`, `SQL/DATA` nodes being online?

   **EDIT**: I tried mysql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-online-add-node-example.html) for adding nodes online but confused and didn't work unless I shutdown all the nodes and remove the logs under `/var/lib/mysql-cluster` on all the nodes.
2. What additional configurations should I include in my `my.conf` file for best performance tuning like `DataMemory` and `IndexMemory`, if anybody using for production, can recommend or paste it here please?

**Update**:3

1. How to convert all the table engines of the database to NDB which are having foreign keys also?

   **EDIT**: I found a script for converting all the table engines but all the tables of my database are not converted as for the error: *ERROR 1217 (23000) at line 11: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails*
2. Is there a way to possess both the features of NDB & InnoDB with cluster and multi-master replication with no risk(down time)?

Comment: Droping MySQL Cluster as it's not completely suitable for web applications(slow `joins`, no support for `Foreign keys`...). Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Oh.., after multiple tries I got it working myself and it has taken upto now. The links are very nice tutorials and I could fix the issues I had this way.

> Also I am not understanding whether mysql-server or mysql-client need to be installed along with mysql-cluster else mysql-cluster alone is enough for running mysqld on SQL nodes.

**A**: I am not sure if `mysql-cluster` works along `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` which are already installed from `apt` but I am sure that those or any extra package are NOT required  for mysql-cluster on Ubuntu as it itself has all the packages. So I can run `mysqld` from cluster extracted package and nothing required for this to install additionally for SQL nodes.

> ./bin/mysqld_safe --user=mysql --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf &

**A**: No need to run `mysqld` manually and instead can use `/etc/init.d/mysql.server start` copying from `/usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server`to start mysqld/SQL node.

> Starting MySQL
>    * Couldn't find MySQL manager (/usr/bin/mysqlmanager) or server (/usr/bin/mysqld_safe)

**A**: The above was the error encountered while trying to start `mysql.server` and that was because I had `mysql-server` and `mysql-client` already installed. Those should be completely removed(I'm not sure if can run cluster successfully along with them) and I did. Those were not completely removed(probably I have to use `apt --purge remove`). Check with `dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql`, if you find `deinstall` then those are not completely uninstalled, which **should** be, else one will have to face above error. Executing below command completely removed them and I could start mysql.server with no errors.

```
aptitude purge $(dpkg --get-selections | grep deinstall | sed s/deinstall//) #To completely remove all deinstall package
pkill -9 mysqld
/etc/init.d/mysql.server
```

> ............ * Manager of pid-file quit without updating file.

**A**: I faced the above error many times in my testing while trying to start `mysql.server`. I could avoid this by simply granting permission on `data` to mysql user like `chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql/data`, this mistake was because I was trying extracting mysql-cluster newly number of times and thus the error as the user `mysql` could not create pid file under data directory for no permission and error log under `/var/lib/mysql-cluster` on sql/data node helped me trace this.

Should be very specific in assigning to **/usr/local/mysql/data**, if you just do `chown -R mysql:mysql /usr/local/mysql` and keep quiet, it won't work and same error is thrown!

After granting permission , check mysqld is working and running by issuing `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p`. Even after entering password you cannot connect and throws error, then mysql root password is not set or you forgot. Use below command to reset mysql root password, and then try connecting again:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqladmin -uroot password your-new-password-here
```

Neither I am satisfied with the answer nor I am willing to accept and award myself as I have many more to do in this clustering. I am willing to update my question with more queries and await to award points to other who is going to answer. UPDATED QUESTION!

Thank you!

### Update

We thought of using MySQL Cluster for production web servers where apache-tomcat serving some static and jsp pages but because of slow `joins`, no support for `foreign keys` and so on... issues which are crucial in our environment and works fine in Innodb engine than NDB, I am ending not using mysql cluster and looking back to replication again though it has sync issues. Thank you!

Comment: It's no much difficult you can easily find googling or in the mysql documentation or use directly use `Mysql Workbench` or `Mysql Administrator` GUI tools if you have it installed. From terminal u can try `CREATE USER 'jeffrey'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypass';` for creating users and `select * from mysql.user;` for listing users. Make sure you execute them in the mysql shell prompt in this case `/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -uroot -p` to login to mysql

Comment: Instead of removing mysql-client, I didn't install it at all. For the time being it seems that my configuration works fine.

Comment: As mysql-cluster uses NDB engine, did you ever think if there is a way of replicating/syncing databases of two different engines(NDO & Innodb)?.

Comment: Documentation says it is possible "Replication from NDB to non-NDB tables.  It is possible to replicate NDB tables from a MySQL Cluster acting as the master to tables using other MySQL storage engines such as InnoDB or MyISAM on a slave mysqld. However, because of differences between the version of mysqld provided with MySQL Cluster and that included with MySQL Server 5.1, the slave server must also use a mysqld binary from the MySQL Cluster distribution" ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-cluster-replication.html But I didn't try.

Comment: Oh..Thanks 'metdos', I was just thinking if it's possible and you've shown the trace of it. I'll try that link. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome, let me know if you succeed.

Comment: Sure!.But I'm still not clear with that. `I(We) want all the features of NDB plus InnoDB`. I am thinking would master-master replication put at risk because of it's defects like write conflicts and rejoining lead to some down time. I could not imagine the structure how it should be with both `cluster and multi-master`. Could you direct me giving some hints if possible?

Comment: Did you try the barracuda engine and files per tables? this will boost your performance big time. also a mysql cluster is for fast reading and safe writing. if you wanna scale up, open a second cluster and move half the data to the other cluster.

I'm using galera and it's working fine so far, not any issues over one year now.